# How to auto enable a plugin after install?

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, php

I am developing a plugin for craft 3 and the plugin just got published to the store.

I can browse through the store and install the plugin but it stays disabled. The user will have to goto Settings -> Plugins and then manually enable the plugin even after installing. Is there a way to auto enable the plugin after install?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

It's because the plugin is doing this in the `init()`:

https://github.com/poptins/craftcms-poptin-app/blob/master/src/Poptin.php#L69-L74

That's basically overwriting Craft's default Project Config settings for a plugin (which is to be enabled).

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/services/Plugins.php#L536-L545

If you keep it there, then you'll have to explicitly set it to enabled in Project Config as well, but ideally, you'll want to move that logic out of `init()` and into something like an `EVENT_AFTER_INSTALL_PLUGIN` event.